# invalid key: content error when deploying project to AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created one project.I deployed this project to AWS Elasticbeanstalk.But this is using port 8081 but i want to run my project on port number 80.For this I created customized config file in my project folder structure
.ebextensions/nginx.config.

```
files:
"/tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf" :
mode: "000755"
owner: ec2-user
group: ec2-user
content: |
     upstream nodejs {
               server 127.0.0.1:80;
               keepalive 256;
     }
         server {
               listen 8082;
               location / {
                    proxy_pass http://nodejs;
                    proxy_set_header Connection "";
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


               }
         }
```

I installed EBCLI in my system.From this I tried to deploy my project then it is giving error

```
ubuntu@ip-127.12.14.12:~/cloudtester$ eb deploy
Creating application version archive "app-150707_0944125".
Uploading cstest/app-150707_094446.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
ERROR: .ebextensions/nginx.config contains the following invalid key: content. For information about valid keys, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.                                

ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

How to solve this error.Thank in advance